# Removing "<pdf:Producer>" from HitHighlighting results in Sharepoint with Foxit PDF IFilter

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-results, xslt, ifilter

In my search results, I am getting something like this included in the HitHighlight section of the result item in the "Search Core Results" web part:

```
<pdf:Producer>MicrosoftÂ® Word 2010
```

This is clearly part of the PDF raw data. Is this something I can exclude from the metadata results or something that needs to be tweaked in the IFilter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which is the crawled property for this metadata and add it to the **ExcludeFromSummary** managed metadata property.

Don't forget to start a full crawl after you modify the property.

Comment: I think it is just part of the full text indexed content. The property is HitHighlights. Some documents show it and some don't, yet they are all indexed pdf files which theoretically should have that data in them.

Comment: If you are certain that this is not a separate crawled property, you can customize the xsl template for the Result and remove the whole summary text if this word is found. Not a very elegant solution.Try to get the whole XML information for one of these files and look if the <pdf:producer> tag is a crawled property. I found mine in ows_MetaInfo with a lot of other crawled properties.